# Suppress automatic SPM package resolution in Xcode 14.3+?

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

Is there a way to suppress automatic SPM package resolution in Xcode 14.3 or later?

###### Why?

Xcode will (usually) automatically re-resolve SPM packages when I change commits, which I do all the time. Because I work on a large project with *lots* of dependencies, package resolution takes a long time (~30-60 seconds). During this time, Xcode's UI is more or less frozen. Which means *I'm* frozen. This workflow bites.

FWIW, the Cocoapods solution to this is far superior:

- fail builds when dependencies are stale
- developer initiates dependency resolution